# rails forms 101

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, forms, post, haml

here's my controller:

```
class TalentController < ApplicationController
  def index
  end

  def new
    @talent = Talent.new
  end

  def create
        @talent.update_attributes!(params)
  end
end
```

here's my app/views/talent/new.html.haml:

```
= "Create new talent"

= form_for @talent, :url => {:action=>:create, :controller=>"talent"}, :method => :post do |f|
  = f.label :First_Name
  = f.text_field :first_name
  = f.label :Last_Name
  = f.text_field :last_name
  = f.label :City
  = f.text_field :city
  = f.label :State
  = f.text_field :state
  = f.label :Zip_code
  = f.text_field :zip_code
  = f.submit "Create"
```

When I hit the create button, I get this error.

```
No route matches [POST] "/talent/new"
```

here's my rake routes:

```
                    /                          {:action=>"index", :controller=>"talent"}
talent_index GET    /talent(.:format)          {:action=>"index", :controller=>"talent"}
             POST   /talent(.:format)          {:action=>"create", :controller=>"talent"}
  new_talent GET    /talent/new(.:format)      {:action=>"new", :controller=>"talent"}
 edit_talent GET    /talent/:id/edit(.:format) {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"talent"}
      talent GET    /talent/:id(.:format)      {:action=>"show", :controller=>"talent"}
             PUT    /talent/:id(.:format)      {:action=>"update", :controller=>"talent"}
             DELETE /talent/:id(.:format)      {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"talent"}
```

What did I miss here??

Comment: Try not specifying `:url` and `:method` for form. Just `= form_for @talent`.

Comment: Also, in your `create` action, you'll get an exception, because `@talent` is not defined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why the form is trying to post to `new`. However, there are some improvements to be made to your code. First of all it is not necessary to pass `:url` and `:method` to `form_for`. The only thing you need is:

```
= form_for @talent do |f|
```

Rails takes care of the rest automatically.

The code in the `create` method of your controller is incorrect. When `create` is called it is a new request and therefore `@talent` will be undefined. You have to set it first. The second mistake is that you are using `update_attributes`, which is used to update an existing record in the database. You want to create a new record, so you have to use `create`. Another way would be to simply create a new instance of `Talent` and call `save` on it.

So, it should look like this:

```
def create
  @talent = Talent.create(params[:talent])
end
```

Or like this:

```
def create
  @talent = Talent.new(params[:talent])
  if @talent.save
    # Saved successfully, do a redirect or something...
  else
    # Validation failed. Show form again so the user can fix his input.
    render :action => 'new'
  end
end
```